# HttpEntity concept while sending HttpPost request

Tags: android, entity, http-post

I know how to send post request in android. I am using the following example code:

```
...
HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(url);
private  ArrayList <NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
private  ArrayList <NameValuePair> headers = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
.....
for(int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(headers.get(i).getValue(),"UTF-8");
    httpPostRequest.setEntity(entity);
}
if(!params.isEmpty()){
    HttpEntity httpEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8);
    httpPostRequest.setEntity(httpEntity);
}

String serverResponse = executeRequest(httpPostRequest);
...
```

I just want to know what is the concept of `HttpEntity`? What idea behind the `HttpEntity` class is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [HTTPEntity](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html) doc: An entity that can be sent or received with an HTTP message. Entities can be found in some [requests](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpEntityEnclosingRequest.html) and in [responses](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html), where they are optional.